# twisted web getPage, 2 clients in 2 classes, manage events between the two

Tags: python, http, client, twisted, twisted.web

i'm trying to create a bridge program in twisted.web that receives data from a web server and sends it to another server, thus i'm using 2 getPage applications that i have wrapped in a class for convenience, the class contains all the callbacks and the client "routine".. 1)auth 2)receive data 3)send data, all this is done in a cyclic way and works perfectly in both clients!!

What i am planning to do now is to integrate the two, this would mean that i would have to make some callbacks outside the classes in order to process them.

client1<--->main<--->client2

How can i do this?

i'm using twisted getPage

i'll post one of the two classes

```
class ChatService():
    def __init__(self):
         self.myServID= self.generatemyServID()
         self.myServServer= "http://localhost"
         ## This is where the magic starts
             reactor.callWhenRunning(self.mainmyServ)
             reactor.run()

    def generatemyServID(self):
         a= ""
         for x in range(60):
            c= floor(random() * 61)
            a += "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[int(c):int(c)+1]
         return a

    def sentMessage(self, data):
        print "Message was sent successfully"

    def sendMessage(self, mess):
        s1= DeferredList([client.getPage(self.myServServer+"/chat/", headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, method="POST", postdata="action=chat&user=%s&message=%s" % (self.myServID, mess)),])
        s1.addCallback(self.sentMessage)
        s1.addErrback(self.errMessage)

    def recivedMessage(self,data):
        chat= loads(data[0][1])
        if chat['from'] != "JOINED" and chat['from'] != "TYPING" and chat['from'] != "Ben":
            print "%s says: %s" % (chat['from'], decode(chat['chat']))
            self.sendMessage("Hello")
        # Restart Loop
        self.loopChat()

    def errMessage(self,e):
            # print "An error occured receiving/sending the messages\n%s" % e
        print "Still no connectiions, waiting..."
        self.loopChat()

    def loopChat(self):
        s1= DeferredList([client.getPage(self.myServServer+"/chat/", headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, method="POST", postdata="action=poll&user=%s&message=null" % self.myServID),])
        s1.addCallback(self.recivedMessage)
        s1.addErrback(self.errMessage)   

    def error(self,e):
        print "An error occured\n%s" % e

    def connectedtomyServService(self,data):
        if data[0][0] == False:
            print "Connection to myServ Service was impossible"
            reactor.stop()
            return
        if loads(data[0][1])['action'] == 'join':
            print "Connected to the server and joined chat"
            print "Started chat loop"
            self.loopChat()
        else:
            print "An Error Occured"
            return

    def mainmyServ(self):
            # print "Client ID is: " + self.myServID
        # Joining Chat
        s1= DeferredList([client.getPage(self.myServServer+"/chat/", headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, method="POST", postdata="action=join&user=%s&message=null" % self.myServID),])
        s1.addCallback(self.connectedtomyServService)
        s1.addErrback(self.error)
```

How can I make callbacks outside the class?

I hope I managed to express myself =D

Thnaks a lot

Comment: reindented perfectly ;) thanks for the tip mattH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make callbacks outside the class?

This sounds like a very common misunderstanding.  As a result of the misunderstanding, the question, as asked, doesn't make a lot of sense.  So let's forget about the question.

You already have some code that's using Deferreds.  Let's start with `mainmyServ`:

```
def mainmyServ(self):
        # print "Client ID is: " + self.myServID
    # Joining Chat
    s1= DeferredList([client.getPage(self.myServServer+"/chat/", headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, method="POST", postdata="action=join&user=%s&message=null" % self.myServID),])
    s1.addCallback(self.connectedtomyServService)
    s1.addErrback(self.error)
```

First, you can get rid of the `DeferredList`.  Your list only has one `Deferred` in it, so the `DeferredList` isn't adding any value.  You'll get practically the same behavior like this, and your callbacks can be simplified by removing all of the `[0][0]` expressions.

```
def mainmyServ(self):
        # print "Client ID is: " + self.myServID
    # Joining Chat
    s1= client.getPage(self.myServServer+"/chat/", headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, method="POST", postdata="action=join&user=%s&message=null" % self.myServID)
    s1.addCallback(self.connectedtomyServService)
    s1.addErrback(self.error)
```

So this is a perfectly reasonable method which is calling a function that returns a Deferred and then adding a callback and an errback to that Deferred.  Say you have another function, perhaps your overall main function:

```
def main():
    service = ChatService()
    service.mainmyServ()
```

What prevents the `main` function from adding more callbacks to the `Deferred` in `mainmyServ`?  Only that `mainmyServ` doesn't bother to return it.  So:

```
def mainmyServ(self):
        # print "Client ID is: " + self.myServID
    # Joining Chat
    s1= client.getPage(self.myServServer+"/chat/", headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, method="POST", postdata="action=join&user=%s&message=null" % self.myServID)
    s1.addCallback(self.connectedtomyServService)
    s1.addErrback(self.error)
    return s1


def main():
    service = ChatService()
    d = service.mainmyServ()
    d.addCallback(doSomethingElse)
```

Nothing special there, it's just another `addCallback`.  All you were missing was a reference to the `Deferred`.

You can set up your loop now, by having `doSomethingElse` call another method on `ChatService`.  If that other method returns a `Deferred`, then `doSomethingElse` can add a callback to it that calls `mainmyServ` again.  And so on.  There's your loop, controlled "outside" of the class.

Comment: This is really nice, thanks for all the time spent in writing this, i have to go now but as soon as i come home i'll try :D
anyways, the reason i am adding deferredLists is because somehow callbacks won't work if they are set alone!! i have noi idea why.

Tell you after how it goes
Thanks again